# Unable to get result from my data class methods when access from ViewController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, viewcontroller

I've created a data class name Person with an integer and a bool instance variables.
Inside my ViewController "initWithNibName" I initialize

```
    anObject = [[Person alloc] init];
```

Inside the View controller have defined an IBAction. I want to toggle the bool value in person class on each click. I can display text on each click and even append it. But unable to print the int value or bool value from my Data Class.

Person.h file

```
   @interface Person : NSObject {

       int pheight;
       BOOL palive;


   }

   -(Person*) init;
   -(void) setPersonheight: (int) h andAlive: (BOOL) pn;
   -(int) personHeight;
   -(void) display;
   -(BOOL) isPersonAlive;

   @end
```

Person.m file

```
   #import "Person.h"


   @implementation Person

   -(Person*) init{

       self = [super init];

    if (self){

        [self setPersonheight:5 andAlive:YES];
    }       

    return self;
   }

   -(void) setPersonheight: (int) h andAlive: (BOOL) pn{

       pheight = h;
    palive = pn;

   }

   -(int) personHeight{

    return pheight;

   }


   -(void) display{

    if(palive){
        palive = NO; 
    }
    else {
        palive = YES;
    }
   }

   -(BOOL) isPersonAlive{

    return YES;

   }

   @end
```

*ViewController.h file

```
   @interface Demo9ViewController : UIViewController {

    UILabel *outlet;
    Person *anObject;
    //id anObject;

   }

   @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *outlet;
   -(IBAction) displayPerson:(id) sender;

   @end
```

*View controller.m file

```
   -(IBAction) displayPerson:(id) sender{

    [anObject display];
    NSString *myPerson = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[anObject personHeight]];
    NSString *string = [outlet.text stringByAppendingString:myPerson];
    outlet.text = string;
   }
```

Can someone tell, what wrong am I doing here ?

Thanks,

Regards,
M Tahir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you correctly hooked up `outlet` to the UILabel?

There are quite a few other problems here with your naming, not using properties, but first make sure you outlets and actions are set up correctly.

What is in `outlet.text`?

Comment: outlet.txt is the outlet for UILabel. For normal cases when the button is clicked the I can update the label to any text I want.

Comment: No, `outlet` is the UILabel outlet, what is the `outlet.text` object? Can you log it and make sure that it is not `nil`?

Comment: No, its not nil, it updates the text on label. Whatever text i assign to it, it updates on the Label.  But the real problem I'm facing is with the Person class. Is there any thing wrong with it. As mentioned above in ViewController class (.m file) I've un-commented the "initWithNibName" and inside it added `anObject = [[Person alloc] init];`

Comment: my question was some what wrong, and also as i am new, I was not using the property correctly.